# How to remove border from stacked column chart in Chartkick - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chart.js, chartkick

I am using chart.js throug chartkick gem.

```
= column_chart [{"name":"A","data":[["2016-07-01",1],["2016-08-01",0],["2016-09-01",0]]},{"name":"B","data":[["2016-07-01",1],["2016-08-01",0],["2016-09-01",0]]}], xtitle: "Date Range", ytitle: "Counts", stacked: true, height: "600px"
```

I am getting following chart:
[image]

I don't want any border around stacked blocks. I want to set border to 0. How can I achieve this using chartkick gem?

I tried adding this on page load in application.js.

```
Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.borderwidth = 0;
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the chart.js library that you have added to your assets. You can set the `dataset.borderWidth` to 0.

Simply replace the `dataset.borderWidth` with 0.

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to figure it out myself but the answer is actually hidden on https://github.com/ankane/chartkick between countless other examples:

`<%= line_chart data, dataset: {borderWidth: 10} %>`

So for a barchart to lose the border it is:

`<%= bar_chart data, dataset: { borderWidth: 0 } %>`